# Using jQuery UI Autocomplete, how can I ensure that one specific result comes up regardless of what text is entered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

My auto-complete source list is a little bit like this:

```
var items = ['UK', 'IE', 'BE', 'NL', 'PLC'];
```

I am trying to make sure that the result set from my auto-complete always contains a 
specific term (in this case PLC).

I have tried is adding PLC to the source list, then overriding the autocomplete result filter (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042903/how-can-i-change-the-result-filter-in-autocomplete)).

I can get it to return "PLC" regardless of what is typed in like this:

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        // The term the user searched for;
        var term = request.term;

        // Extract matching items:
        var matches = $.grep(items, function(item, index) {
            return /PLC/.test(item);
        });

        // let autocomplete know the results:
        response(matches);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GarethPN/xbZhr/6/

But how would I use the term variable in the regular expression to retain the standard functionality?

Or is there a blindingly obvious easier way that I'm missing?

Comment: Just add it to your source. This is how i did it. Autocomplete does the ajax call to fetch the data. On the backend I create a variable with the options I always want to returns, search my DB , and concatenate the reultes to my variable and output the string. The value gets returned first no matter what the user typed. The reason it gets shown first is because I concatenate my results after it. IF i want it to be dispalyed at the bottom of the autocomplete ly I would reverse the order.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to use the auto-complete ajax control toolkit control now, instead of jqueryui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is to create an array of matching result and adding PLC to them:

```
var items = ['UK', 'IE', 'FR', 'BE', 'NL'];
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        // The term the user searched for;
        var term = request.term;

        var matches = [];
        matches.push('PLC');/(add PLC
        // Extract matching items: (write your own function here)


        // let autocomplete know the results:
        response(matches);
    }
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xbZhr/8/

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to use the auto-complete ajax control toolkit control now, instead of jqueryui.  There have been a few requirement alterations (which is nice).

The code you provided returns PLC on it's own, I think I would need to write a callback function to handle the search event.